# How to migrate data from Google AppEngine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, migration, gae-datastore, dump

How to migrate data from Google AppEngine's Datastore to other database (not Datastore)?

There is `appcfg.py download_data` but it produces sqlite3 file with empty `bulkloader_database_signature` and useless `result` tables.

Comment: Have you tried anything else besides appcfg.py?

Answer (score 1):

I think [approcket](https://github.com/k7d/approcket/) can help you. It syncs data from GAE datastore to mysql. Is this what you ask for?

Comment: Can you provide any demonstrative code that shows how it syncs the data, or provide a rundown of how it helps?

Comment: I'll try to put some code together, in the meantime, see the approcket's wiki: https://github.com/k7d/approcket/wiki/Gettings-Started